# Creating animation on ImageView while changing image resource

Tags: android

I have only one `ImageView` in my layout and I am changing its resource when a gasture event detected. I just want to show an animation while changing resource of ImageView. Can I use `ViewFlipper` with `one` ImageView?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For a single imageview you can use this helper function:

```
public static void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v, final Bitmap new_image) {
    final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, android.R.anim.fade_out); 
    final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, android.R.anim.fade_in); 
    anim_out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            v.setImageBitmap(new_image); 
            anim_in.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
            });
            v.startAnimation(anim_in);
        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim_out);
}
```

Comment: This is actually a very good answer although the animation doesn't match with what this questions need.

Comment: This code works, however setting anim_in listener is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 19):

Here's an example using [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) like @Konstantin Burov suggested:

Add this `ImageSwitcher` element to your xml layout:

```
<ImageSwitcher
   android:id="@+id/slide_trans_imageswitcher"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageSwitcher>
```

Create in and out animations in `res/anim/`:

Out animation:

```
//left_to_right_out.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

And in animation:

```
//left_to_right_in.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Initialize them in your code:

```
        Animation in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right_out);
```

Initialize your `ImageSwitcher`:

```
private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.slide_trans_imageswitcher);
```

Attach the animations to it:

```
imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
```

Now everytime you set an image resource for `imageSwitcher`, it will switch in a slide animation.

---

For example we can change the image every X seconds:

```
private int animationCounter = 1;
private Handler imageSwitcherHandler;
imageSwitcherHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
imageSwitcherHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch (animationCounter++) {
            case 1:
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                break;
            case 3:
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                break;
        }
        animationCounter %= 4;
        if(animationCounter == 0 ) animationCounter = 1;

        imageSwitcherHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: does not support vector

Comment: You need to define ImageView factory aswell, otherwise you'll get a nasty crash without a stactrace. `is.setFactory( () -> { new ImageView(this) } );`

Answer (score 9):

I found another way to animate it using transition drawable(I took idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443570/5541688))

```
public static void setImageDrawableWithAnimation(ImageView imageView,
                                                 Drawable drawable,
                                                 int duration) {
    Drawable currentDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    if (currentDrawable == null) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        return;
    }

    TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
            currentDrawable,
            drawable
    });
    imageView.setImageDrawable(transitionDrawable);
    transitionDrawable.startTransition(duration);
}
```

Analogous kotlin extension function:

```
fun ImageView.setImageDrawableWithAnimation(drawable: Drawable, duration: Int = 300) {
    val currentDrawable = getDrawable()
    if (currentDrawable == null) {
        setImageDrawable(drawable)
        return
    }

    val transitionDrawable = TransitionDrawable(arrayOf(
            currentDrawable,
            drawable
    ))
    setImageDrawable(transitionDrawable)
    transitionDrawable.startTransition(duration)
}
```

If your drawables contains transparent parts, this flag could be useful to prevent old drawable visibility:

```
transitionDrawable.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Rotate3dAnimation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html) available in the API demo app.
View > Animation > 3D transition

You can also [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android) question on SO