# How to play video automatically in a series with images ?

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to play video after showing all image. My code for image play one by one every 10 sec is given below. I want to implement with this code a video also play means I have 5 image which are play one by one every 10 sec when 5 image show then a video play automatically and after completion of video image are again play. All images and video play in cycle.

Following is my code,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
 {
    private ViewFlipper myviewflipper;
    private float initialXpoint;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myviewflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myflipper);
    myviewflipper.setAutoStart(true);
    myviewflipper.setFlipInterval(10000);
    myviewflipper.startFlipping();
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
   {
      switch (touchevent.getAction())
     {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        initialXpoint = touchevent.getX();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float finalX = touchevent.getX();
        if (initialXpoint > finalX)
           {
              if (myviewflipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
               break;
               myviewflipper.showNext();
           }
        else
          {
               if (myviewflipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
              break;
              myviewflipper.showPrevious();
          }
          break;
      }
       return false;
    }
 }
```

my xml fil-

```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">
       <ViewFlipper
     android:id="@+id/myflipper"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/b" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/c" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/d" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/e" />

      </ViewFlipper>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes sir like as slide show....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use view switcher or ViewFlipper if your images are static that means they are predefined in xml.

[ViewFlipper Sample](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/image-slideshow-using-viewflipper-in-android/)

Or you can use Thread and Handler pattern

Idea: Take ImageView in xml , Take array of Images, First set 0th image to ImageView after 10 secs set 1st so on..., You can add image along with simple Animation we have in Android.

[Sample](http://manisivapuram.blogspot.in/2011/06/slideshow-of-images-using-android.html)

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183532)

Comment: thankyou sir.for but after completion of images i want play video automatically.how can i do this.

Comment: @user3247529 I am not sir :) .Video means?

Comment: means that after playing all images play a video file also for given time.

Comment: You have that video file or url with you?

Comment: i have that video file in sd card or in raw folder in res

Comment: Then get it from SD card and play using VideoView which is available in android. Search it first dude "get video from SD card , Play video using VideoView"

Comment: i searched and implement this task it work fine but i want play video simultaneously after completion of images without any user interface means when images complete one cycle then video play