# How to change image periodically inside CollapsingToolbarLayout android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to rotate multiple images periodically inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like [Google Play Newsstand Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines)

I have uploaded 3 screenshots of that app here: 
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRKyS.png)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdtQh.png)
[Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRSh7.png)

I have created `CollapsingToolbarLayout` using below code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

How to change image periodically(after some specific interval) inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` ?

**Note :** [Look at here for creating animation on ImageView while changing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161500/creating-animation-on-imageview-while-changing-image-resource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get a reference to the `ImageView` using `findViewById()`
2. You need a `Runnable` which will update the image displayed in the `ImageView`
3. You can use the `postDelayed()` method of a [Hanlder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to run the `Runnable` code periodically

   ```
   final Handler handler = new Handler();   
   final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

       @Override   
       public void run() {   
           //TODO: update image here   
           handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);   
       }   
   }   
   handler.postDelayed(runnable, INTERVAL);
   ```

Comment: What about the less-known ViewAnimator widget?

Comment: @WindRider it's a valid option, depending on the use case.