# using animation in imageview while changing image

Tags: android, animation

I have used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183532/3990512) to animate changing image of an ImageView. But it converts the first image to a white screen and then fade the white screen into the final image (no matter if I use background for ImageView or not). 
the same effect is appeared when using `slide_out_right` and `slide_in_left`.

**Question:**

How can I directly go from current Image to a new Image using a custom Animation?

- I know that it is possible when using ImageSwitcher but I wanne do it in an ImageView
- `TransitionDrawable` is not the solution because it is applicable only for fade. I wanna use translate or any custom animation.

thanks for any help

**Edit:**

I think I got the answere, but I am not sure if it an efficient solution:

the white screen is because I am animating the whole ImageView. when it goes out the display what appeared is the Layout background which is white.

To solve the problem, I used two ImageViews and copy the current Image to one and the new image to the another one. animation_in is applied to the imageview containing new image and animation_out to the other one.

Comment: Could you check the link at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5151774/1349601 and see if this helps you create the effect that you are looking for

Comment: It is not what exactly I am search for. Please check my Edit, it works, although I am not sure if it a good solution is.