# How to remove lag when Rotate Animation repeats on Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, rotateanimation

I have built a `RotateAnimation` in an XML, load it with `AnimationUtils` and set it to an `ImageView`. The problem I face is that, when the image is back to its initial position after one round, instead of proceeding straight to the next round, there is a small timeout there, like a lag.

Is there any solution to remove this timeout?

Below you may find the xml of the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <rotate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="1800"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="360"/>
</set>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634252/1402846

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to put the linear_interpolator on the set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:duration="1800"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="360"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up the increasing the `android:toDegrees` to above 360 like 3600 according to needs. The rotation is smooth now.