# Android: Rotate image in imageview by an angle

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, imageview

I am using the following code to rotate a image in ImageView by an angle. Is there any simpler and less complex method available.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageviewid);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(txtViewsid);
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageid);
mat.postRotate(Integer.parseInt(degree));===>angle to be rotated
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
iv.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

Comment: PS for 2014, it looks like you can simply set "rotation" in the XML in Android Studio. (You can even just click the "expert properties" button on the right, if you can't be bothered using the 'Text' layout!)

Comment: find answer right here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983423/5872337

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Another simple way to rotate an `ImageView`:
**UPDATE:**
Required imports:

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

Code: (Assuming `imageView`, `angle`, `pivotX` & `pivotY` are already defined)

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

This method does not require creating a new bitmap each time.

> NOTE: To rotate an `ImageView` on *ontouch* at runtime you can
>   set *onTouchListener* on `ImageView` & rotate it by adding last two
>   lines(i.e. *postRotate* matrix & set it on *imageView*) in above code
>   section in your touch listener *ACTION_MOVE* part.

Comment: For completeness here is the line based on the `ImageView`'s values: `matrix.postRotate( 180f, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);`

Comment: how to rotate imageview on every touch event?

Comment: for me, if rotated in a relativeLayout the imageView grows to the size of the image contained, not fitting into the layout anymore. Does anybody have experience how to solve this?

Comment: Note: for this to work, you have to set your `ImageView`'s `src` attribute. `getDrawable()` was returning null for me until I realized that I had set the `ImageView`'s `background` attribute instead of `src`. *facepalm*

Comment: @StefanHoth if i already have the bitmap, i can just use the width and the height of it, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, that should work as long it's the same bitmap regarding size.

Comment: @StefanHoth what if I want to do both rotation and then center-crop on the imageView ? can you please help me out on this? I've made a post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948973/how-to-preview-images-from-the-gallery-in-the-correct-way . the reason I need to rotate is described there.

Comment: It rotates the image in imageview only.  What should I do to rotate the image itself too?

Comment: @StefanHoth what about if i use `imageView.getWidth() / 2`?

Comment: @Makibo Hi, did you find some solution to it?

Comment: which imports do i have to add for this to work? Almost everything is red. Also, it says new matrix() is depriciated.

Comment: I did this on in `onConfigurationChanged` but it is not working any idea?
I am trying to rotate image when screen orientation changes

Comment: @Makibo yes, the image size is changing after rotation (because it is a rectangle). If you display it with the same coordinates (upper left corner), it looks shifted. Yet, you can adjust it: `X -= ( img.getWidth() - originalImgageWidth ) / 2;`

Comment: BTW you can get the pivotX/Y by calling imageView.getPivotX/Y

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402429/19856629

Answer (score 223):

`mImageView.setRotation(angle)` with API>=11

Comment: would it also change the width and height of the view to the correct size ? or does it change only how it looks?

Comment: Is there a way to have a "rotation animation" while rotating?

Comment: @IvanMorgillo You can have a look at `ViewPropertyAnimator`, which is used like `aView.animate().rotation(20).start()`

Comment: @IvanMorgillo: Use `rotationBy()`. For example, `view.animate().rotationBy(180f).start()`. But it becomes problematic if the view is clicked successively.

Comment: I'm using this code in a button. The first click is ok, But the next clicks doesn't rotate anymore. Should I put some other line to fix this?

Comment: it reverses the height and width of image view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402429/19856629

Answer (score 107):

If you're supporting API 11 or higher, you can just use the following XML attribute:

```
android:rotation="90"
```

It might not display correctly in Android Studio xml preview, but it works as expected.

Comment: The hint regarding the xml preview helped me a lot

Comment: The XML preview is displaying for me properly after rotation is applied.

Comment: This will rotate the view but not the image! This will add blank areas beside the image. Just add a `background` to see the effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402429/19856629

Answer (score 47):

There are two ways to do that:

1 Using `Matrix` to create a new bitmap:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(30);

Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
        matrix, true);

imageView.setImageBitmap(rotated);
```

2 use `RotateAnimation` on the `View` you want to Rotate, and make sure the Animation set to `fillAfter=true`, `duration=0`, and `fromDegrees=toDgrees`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="45"
  android:toDegrees="45"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="0"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

and Inflate the Animation in code:

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
myView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Comment: danx..
But is dere ny way to  do  RotateAnimation on the View dynamically..i mean to set d angle dynamically..

Comment: this works better than the accepted answer if the image you need to rotate is in a ListView

Comment: @rijinrv Animation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(currentRotation, currentRotation -= 90, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(100);
            rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            photoView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);

Answer (score 11):

I know this is insanely late, but it was helpful for me so it may help others.

As of API 11, you can set the absolute rotation of an ImageView programmatically by using the `imageView.setRotation(angleInDegrees);` method.

By absolute, I mean you can repeatedly call this function without having to keep track of the current rotation. Meaning, if I rotate by passing `15F` to the `setRotation()` method, and then call `setRotation()` again with `30F`, the image's rotation with be 30 degrees, not 45 degrees.

**Note:** This actually works for any subclass of the **View** object, not just ImageView.

Comment: My image at rotating gets naturally a little bit higher on the page. How can I set it down?

Comment: Is your image centered properly? If you have an uneven amount of transparency in your image, rotation can cause it to appear to change position when rotating

Comment: No man, when image rotates it uses the axis. Imagine your cellphone in vertical position on your hand, now rotate it to horizontal. It doesn't touch your hand any more. So there's a space... But I solved it by using setPivotX()

Answer (score 10):

For Kotlin,

```
mImageView.rotation = 90f //angle in float
```

This will rotate the imageView rather than rotating the image

Also, though its a method in `View` class. So you can pretty much rotate any view using it.

Answer (score 7):

Can also be done this way:-

```
imageView.animate().rotation(180).start();
```

[got from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209711/7168430)

Comment: Thanks! It's very easy and quick

Comment: can we set an anchor too?
I'm planning not giving the animation but the drag effect for rotating with an anchor,... if that's possible? @Debasish

Answer (score 7):

Rotate an image in android with delay:

```
imgSplash.animate().rotationBy(360f).setDuration(3000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my [implementation of RotatableImageView](https://github.com/petrnohejl/Android-Templates-And-Utilities/tree/master/Src-RotatableImageView). Usage is very easy: just copy *attrs.xml* and *RotatableImageView.java* into your project and add RotatableImageView to your layout. Set desired rotation angle using *example:angle* parameter.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.example.views.RotatableImageView
        android:id="@+id/layout_example_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_layout_arrow"
        example:angle="180" />
</FrameLayout>
```

If you have some problems with displaying image, try change code in *RotatableImageView.onDraw()* method or use draw() method instead.

Comment: I got a NullPointerException while using RotatableImageView.
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
  {
    int w=getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    ...
  }
BTW, I was use it in code(and have a given default image), not in xml.

Comment: this imageView has weird issues when being used in a gridView. it keeps getting invisible till you scroll.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you want to rotate an ImageView by **180 degrees** vertically or horizontally, you can use `scaleY` or `scaleX` properties and set them to `-1f`. Here is a Kotlin example:

```
imageView.scaleY = -1f
imageView.scaleX = -1f
```

`1f` value is used to return an ImageView to its normal state:

```
imageView.scaleY = 1f
imageView.scaleX = 1f
```

Comment: How to rotate 90 degree?

Answer (score 3):

I have a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970311/9139265) to this.
Actually it is a solution to a problem that arises after rotation(Rectangular image doesn't fit ImagView)
but it covers your problem too..
Although this Solution has Animation for better or for worse

```
    int h,w;
    Boolean safe=true;
```

Getting the parameters of imageView is not possible at initialisation of activity
To do so please refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680660/9139265)
**OR** set the dimensions at onClick of a Button Like this

```
    rotateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(imageView.getRotation()/90%2==0){
                h=imageView.getHeight();
                w=imageView.getWidth();

            }
        .
        .//Insert the code Snippet below here 
       }
```

And the code to be run when we want to rotate ImageView

```
if(safe)     
imageView.animate().rotationBy(90).scaleX(imageView.getRotation()/90%2==0?(w*1.0f/h):1).scaleY(imageView.getRotation()/90%2==0?(w*1.0f/h):1).setDuration(2000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                      safe=false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                      safe=true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

This solution is sufficient for the Problem above.Although it will shrink the imageView even if it is not necessary(when height is smaller than Width).If it bothers you,you can add another ternary operator inside scaleX/scaleY.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best method :)

```
int angle = 0;
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            angle = angle + 90;
            imageView.setRotation(angle);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can we set anchor while rotating?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use **rotation** atribute of ImageView

Below is the attribute from ImageView with details from Android source

```
<!-- rotation of the view, in degrees. -->
<attr name="rotation" format="float" />
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a nice solution for putting a rotated drawable for an imageView:

```
Drawable getRotateDrawable(final Bitmap b, final float angle) {
    final BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b) {
        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle, b.getWidth() / 2, b.getHeight() / 2);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    };
    return drawable;
}
```

usage:

```
Bitmap b=...
float angle=...
final Drawable rotatedDrawable = getRotateDrawable(b,angle);
root.setImageDrawable(rotatedDrawable);
```

another alternative:

```
private Drawable getRotateDrawable(final Drawable d, final float angle) {
    final Drawable[] arD = { d };
    return new LayerDrawable(arD) {
        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle, d.getBounds().width() / 2, d.getBounds().height() / 2);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    };
}
```

also, if you wish to rotate the bitmap, but afraid of OOM, you can use an NDK solution i've made [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images)

Answer (score 2):

It is too late for the answer, someone may found this useful, I came across a situation where I need to animate the rotation og `ImageView` by some `angle` on first `ClickListener` event, and then on the 2nd `ClickListener` event, need to `rotate` back the image to the original angle. this is how this magic happened

```
fun rotateAnim(imageView: ImageView,angle : Float){
    imageView.isEnabled = false
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ${imageView.rotation}")
    val rotation = imageView.animate().rotationBy(angle)
    rotation.interpolator = FastOutSlowInInterpolator()
    rotation.startDelay = 200
    rotation.setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
           imageView.isEnabled = true
        }
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}

    })
    rotation.start()
}
```

and implementation is like

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    val rotation = imageView.rotation
    if(rotation == 180F){
         rotateAnim(imageView,90F)
    }else{
         rotateAnim(imageView,-90F)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think there is. The `Matrix` class is responsible for all image manipulations, whether it's rotating, shrinking/growing, skewing, etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

My apologies, but I can't think of an alternative. Maybe someone else might be able to, but the times I've had to manipulate an image I've used a Matrix.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this  on a custom view

```
public class DrawView extends View {


    public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        /*Canvas c=new Canvas(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_minute1)    );

        c.rotate(45);*/

        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_minute1), 0, 0, null);
        canvas.rotate(45);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to rotate the view visually you can use:

```
iv.setRotation(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

if u want to rotate an image by 180 degrees then put these two value in imageview tag:-

```
android:scaleX="-1"
android:scaleY="-1"
```

Explanation:- scaleX = 1 and scaleY = 1 repesent it's normal state but if we put -1 on scaleX/scaleY property then it will be rotated by 180 degrees

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin:

```
imageView.rotation = degrees.toFloat()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to create your own custom Image view(say `RotateableImageView extends ImageView` )...and override the onDraw() to rotate either the canvas/bitmaps before redering on to the canvas.Don't forget to restore the canvas back.

But if you are going to rotate only a single instance of image view,your solution should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

without matrix and animated:

```
{
    img_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    rotate = new RotateAnimation(0 ,300);
    rotate.setDuration(500);
    img_view.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just write this in your onactivityResult

```
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.postRotate((270)); //degree how much you rotate i rotate 270
            Bitmap bMapRotate=Bitmap.createBitmap(yourSelectedImage, 0,0,yourSelectedImage.getWidth(),yourSelectedImage.getHeight(), mat, true);
            image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
            Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);
            image.setBackground(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 100% working;

On rotate button click write this code:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(bitmap==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image photo is not yet set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                ivImageProduct.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
                matrix.postRotate(90,ivImageProduct.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2,ivImageProduct.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
                Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap=bmp;
                ivImageProduct.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than convert image to bitmap and then rotate it try to rotate direct image view like below code.

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);

AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animSet.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

final RotateAnimation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, -90.0f,
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

animRotate.setDuration(1500);
animRotate.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.addAnimation(animRotate);

myImageView.startAnimation(animSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below answer for continuous rotation of an imageview

```
int i=0;
```

If rotate button clicked

```
imageView.setRotation(i+90);
i=i+90;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX); //required
matrix.postRotate((float) 20, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

how to use?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   int view = R.layout.activity_main;
   TextView textChanger;
   ImageView imageView;
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(view);
      textChanger = findViewById(R.id.textChanger);
      imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      textChanger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            roateImage(imageView);
         }
      });
   }
   private void roateImage(ImageView imageView) {
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX); //required
      matrix.postRotate((float) 20, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2,    imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
      imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added several solution. If you want to rotate image on click btn and image size must be fill parent layout. You can also use https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970311/9139265 this code also works

```
        ImageView photoView = findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
        ImageView rotateBtn = findViewById(R.id.rotate_image);
        FrameLayout photoFrame = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.photoFrame);

        final float[] currentRotation = {0f};
        final boolean[] isFirst = {true};
        final boolean[] isInitial = {true};
        final float[] firstWidth = {0};
        final float[] firstHeight = {0};
        final float[] secondWidth = {0};
        final float[] secondHeight = {0};

        rotate_image.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (isInitial[0]) {
                isInitial[0] = false;

                firstWidth[0] = photoView.getWidth();
                firstHeight[0] = photoView.getHeight();

                float frameWidth = photoFrame.getWidth();
                float frameHeight = photoFrame.getHeight();

                if (firstHeight[0] >= firstWidth[0]) {
                    float imageRatio = firstHeight[0] / firstWidth[0];
                    if (frameHeight > frameWidth) {
                        secondWidth[0] = frameWidth;
                        secondHeight[0] = secondWidth[0] / imageRatio;
                    } else {
                        secondHeight[0] = frameHeight;
                        secondWidth[0] = secondHeight[0] * imageRatio;
                    }
                } else {
                    float imageRatio = firstWidth[0] / firstHeight[0];
                    float frameRatio = frameHeight / frameWidth;
                    if (imageRatio >= frameRatio) {
                        secondHeight[0] = frameHeight;
                        secondWidth[0] = secondHeight[0] / imageRatio;
                    } else {
                        secondWidth[0] = frameWidth;
                        secondHeight[0] = secondWidth[0] * imageRatio;
                    }
                }
            }

            float imageWidth = isFirst[0] ? secondWidth[0] : firstHeight[0];
            float imageHeight = isFirst[0] ? secondHeight[0] : firstWidth[0];
            
            isFirst[0] = !isFirst[0];
        // You can use custom animation
        //Animation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(currentRotation, 
        //currentRotation -= 90, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
        //Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        //rotateAnimation.setDuration(100);
        //rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        //photoView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);

            photoView.animate().rotation(currentRotation[0] -= 90).start();
            photoView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) imageWidth;
            photoView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) imageHeight;
            photoView.requestLayout();
        });
```

My xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/photoFrame"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rotate_image"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/photo_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_client_photo_nophoto" />
  </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rotate_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rotate_image"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I maked another solution without animation and it worked with image file:

```
    ImageView photoView = findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
    ImageView rotate_image = findViewById(R.id.rotate_image);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(file)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(photoView);
    
    rotate_image.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        rotateImageFile(file.getPath());
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(file)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(photoView);

    });

public void rotateImageFile(String imagePath) {
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

        switch (orientation) {
            case 1:
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90));
                break;
            case 6:
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180));
                break;
            case 3:
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270));
                break;
            case 8:
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));
                break;
        }
        exif.saveAttributes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another solution works with Bitmap but without animation, quality can decrease and rotate can be not smoothly, test it.

```
ImageView photoView = findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
ImageView rotate_image = findViewById(R.id.rotate_image);
final Bitmap[] bitmap = {BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath())};
//If you dont use file add this code inside of setOnClickListener
//bitmap[0] =((BitmapDrawable) photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    rotate_image.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    //bitmap[0] =((BitmapDrawable) photoView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    bitmap[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap[0], 0, 0, bitmap[0].getWidth(), bitmap[0].getHeight(), matrix, true);
    photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap[0]);
});
```

I added link address above and it is example code:

```
    ImageView photoView = findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
    ImageView rotate_image = findViewById(R.id.rotate_image);

        rotate_image.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        float scale = photoView.getRotation() % 180 == 0 ? (float) photoView.getWidth() / photoView.getHeight() : 1.0f;
        photoView.animate().rotationBy(90).scaleX(scale).scaleY(scale).setDuration(100).start();
    });
```