# How to rotate android.graphics.Picture

Tags: android, graphics, image, screen-rotation

How to rotate android.graphics.Picture 90 degrees?

*Note: No its not in Bitmap form

Comment: You mean [like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8981845/102937)

Comment: No its of class android.graphics.Picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are overriding `onDraw()` then you can do the following:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(90f, picture.getWidth()/2, picture.getHeight/2);
canvas.drawPicture(picture);
canvas.restore();
```

If you only want to rotate the image itself then you could use this method:

```
public Picture rotatePicture(float degrees, Picture picture) {
    int width = picture.getWidth();
    int height = picture.getHeight();

    Picture rotatedPicture = new Picture();
    Canvas canvas = rotatedPicture.beginRecording(width, height);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(degrees, width/2, height/2);
    picture.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    rotatedPicture.endRecording();

    return rotatedPicture;
}
```

Comment: I actually do this but it depends what you're trying to accomplish. c.drawPicture(picture, r);
         

         c.save();
         c.rotate(90f, picture.getWidth()/2, picture.getHeight()/2);
         c.restore();