# Rotating bitmap causes outOfMemoryException

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am rotating a bitmap this way, on every button click the image rotates 90 degrees

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotated, 0, 0,
        rotated.getWidth(), rotated.getHeight(), matrix, true);
iv.setImageBitmap(rotated);
```

I tried this with a lot of images, but now one caused an OutOfMemoryError. Is there a way to prevent this? Of course I can call recycle, but then I lose the bitmap and have to get it again from the imageview. I don't think that will make any difference.

Comment: Might this help? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: If rotating the ImageView is an alternative, go with that!

Comment: Rotating the ImageView isn't an option, I save the bitmap afterwards. Though in other situations it is a better option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have suggestions for you.

1) When you have any memory hunger task, use in methods and if possible with `AsyncTask`.
2) Declare objects as `WeakReference`. This will give you chance to release memory after use. See below example.

```
public class RotateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private WeakReference<ImageView> imgInputView;
    private WeakReference<Bitmap> rotateBitmap;

    public RotateTask(ImageView imgInputView){
        this.imgInputView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imgInputView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //if you want to show progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        rotateBitmap = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(Bitmap.createBitmap(rotated, 0, 0,rotated.getWidth(), rotated.getHeight(), matrix, true));
        return rotateBitmap.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //dismiss progress dialog
        imgInputView.get().setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

This task has all the views and object as `WeakReference`. When this task is completed, all the memory used by this Task is free. Try this approach. I used in my application.

Comment: This is a life saver at 4:00 AM in the morning.

Comment: Glad that helped you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Like Below:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotated, 0, 0,rotated.getWidth(), rotated.getHeight(), matrix, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
rotated.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, bmpStream);
iv.setImageBitmap(rotated);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just view the images, you can set a rotate drawable as [**shown here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376031/878126)

If you care about real rotation of the bitmap, and you also want to avoid OOM, check [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images)