# Android: Rotate image in ImageView by 90degrees but without delay

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation, imageview

I am developing a game where a user needs to tap on the image in ImageView to rotate it. On each tap image rotates by 90 degrees in clockwise direction.
But image is taking time to rotate from old to new position. This is hampering the gameplay experience. I have used the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{  
... 
...  
    imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
    imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override 
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
              matrix.postRotate(90); 
              Bitmap myImg = getBitmapFromDrawable(imgview.getDrawable());
              Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg,0,0,myImg.getWidth(),myImg.getHeight(),matrix,true);
              imgview.setImageBitmap(rotated);
         }
});
```

I want to know is there any **other way to rotate** the image
**without creating any delay** in rotation.

Comment: You can try this: [ANDROID::Rotate image in imageview by an angle][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I also tried to do it once and couldn't find any other solution but using animation. Here how I'd do.

```
private void rotate(float degree) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    imgview.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}
```

Comment: No, you can put this inside the onclick method directly. You don't need to do anything else. imgview.startAnimation(rotateAnim); directly rotates the image

Comment: Ok, now I am rotating the image by 90, 180, 270 and 360 degrees using degree = degree + 90 . But the image is first going back to its original position than rotating to the given deree

Comment: For that (I am not sure) you can set the from-degree of the animation. new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree, ... The first two parameters are the degrees "from" and "to". If you know that what degree that you are rotating from you can set the first param with that value. That may solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I used rotate(float fromDegree,float toDegree){...} and stored fromDegree = toDegree and toDegree = toDegree + 90;

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to rotate the object, rotating the view should be enough.
If you are aiming API>=11 you can always do this.

```
mImageView.setRotation(angle);
```

Cheers.

Comment: if this is clicked again, the rotate button, it doesn't work. That is, two clicks doesn't rotate the view by 180. Instead keeps still at 90. Is there a way to accomplish multiple rotations on button click ?

Comment: @KritikaJalan For this you simply need to have a counter that counts the number of clicks. `onClick(){ counter++; imageView.setRotation(counter*90)};`

Comment: Yeah, I did it instead using:
img.setRotation(img.getRotation()- 90f);

Thanks, @BarthyB.

Answer (score 5):

Short method

`View.animate().rotation(90).setDuration(0);`

Answer (score -3):

did you try to use a custom view extending imageview and rotating the image in a background thread?

Comment: please give an example for doing that, the image should be roatated on user's tap only

Comment: As such, this is rather a comment than an answer. I know you don't have the rep yet for commenting though.

Comment: @laalto yes i know i apologize for that. Anyway you should create a rotatio method in your custom view with a degree parameter and then from such method you launch an asynctask which do something like this: 1- rotates the bitmap of 1 or more degrees 2- set the bitmap as imageview resource 3- invalidate the view. Do this all thing until you reach the value of degrees passed in this method. In this way you should have an animation without delays and you can even decide the duration of the animation and the smoothness