# Image drawable rotation not working android?

Tags: android, imageicon, image-rotation

I need to rotate image icon from drawable using xml attributes i have tried it in different way but nothing seems working.

> android:rotation="90"
>
> android:fromDegrees="0"
>
> android:toDegrees="360"
>
> android:pivotX="50%"
>
> android:pivotY="50%"

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_collapse" />
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work after compiling:

```
android:rotation="90"
```

You can't see it on your Preview but it's working after installing on the emulator.

If you had any problems, use Java:

[Android: Rotate image in ImageView by 90degrees but without delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735280/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-90degrees-but-without-delay)

Comment: For the programmatically way :)

Comment: Yeah well sometimes programatically way will do the same but with more power, something like that :) goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable file like this..

**rotate.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_collapse">
</rotate>
```

define this file drawable folder

In `ImageView`, use: `android:background="@drawable/rotate"`