# draw image in diagonal position android

Tags: android, imageview, surfaceview, drawbitmap

I am a newbie here and I'd like to ask about Bitmaps. Is the image below possible?

[image]

I just want a bitmap image to display diagonally or in any position other than horizontal. I'm using `SurfaceView` but for the mean time while testing this, I'm just using `ImageView`. Help. *faints*

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are rotating an ImageView you can use a [PropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#view-prop-animator).

`ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0f, 45f);`