# I want to rotate image which is generated from its thumbnail

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

```
Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videopathbundle,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

In the above code am able to get the thumbnail from video file path. But the image is set in landscape mode. So am now want to rotate and show the image in portrait or vertical. I tried other methods but am not able to get its width and height for rotating the same.

Friends Please help me on this.

I changed it to drawable and then tried to rotate the image but its throwing error on calculating width and height.

```
Drawable d= new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bMap);
Bitmap finalThumb = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
Bitmap bmresult = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalThumb);
Canvas tempcanvas = new Canvas(bmresult);
tempcanvas.rotate(90);
tempcanvas.drawBitmap(bmresult, 0, 0, null);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Imageview videoThumb.setImageBitmap(bmresult );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle

Comment: @reactivemobile but it is showing empty image where i have to set Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below method for rotate your bitmap base on specific angle

```
public static Bitmap Rotate(Bitmap _input, float _angle)
{
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(_angle);
      return Bitmap.createBitmap(_input, 0, 0, _input.getWidth(), _input.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

for call Rotate(myBmp,90);
```

Comment: _input refers to bitmap or its location. Because i cannot fetch the location, I can only use bitmap object

Comment: this method get bitmap and rotate then return bitmap,