# How to rotate image in imageview on button click each time?

Tags: java, android, imageview

This is java code.I am getting image from image gallery.I have one Button and one ImageView. It is rotating only one time.When I again click button it is not rotating image.

```
public class EditActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
private Button rotate;
private ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    rotate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_rotate1);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImage);
    String path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 510, 500,
            false));
    rotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
          {                  
            imageView.setRotation(90);


        }
    });



}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ANDROID::Rotate image in imageview by an angle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

Comment: I'd just like to bring to notice that this question requires successive rotations that then complete a full circle. The proposed duplicate on the other hand will rotate by a quadrant and keep repeating the same over and over again.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change your `onClick()` method to

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{                  
    imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + 90);
}
```

Notice, what the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)) say

> Sets the degrees that the view is rotated around the pivot point. **Increasing values result in clockwise rotation.**

---

I'd like to update my answer to show how to use `RotateAnimation` to achieve the same effect in case you're also targeting Android devices running Gingerbread (v10) or below.

```
private int mCurrRotation = 0; // takes the place of getRotation()
```

Introduce an instance field to track the rotation degrees as above and use it as:

```
mCurrRotation %= 360;
float fromRotation = mCurrRotation;
float toRotation = mCurrRotation += 90;

final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(
        fromRotation, toRotation, imageview.getWidth()/2, imageView.getHeight()/2);

rotateAnim.setDuration(1000); // Use 0 ms to rotate instantly 
rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true); // Must be true or the animation will reset

imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

Usually one can setup such [View animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) through XML as well. But, since you have to specify absolute degree values in there, successive rotations will repeat themselves instead of building upon the previous one to complete a full circle. Hence, I chose to show how to do it in code above.

Comment: @Darpan Thanks for your feedback. I've added an update to show how to support the rotate animation on Gingerbread or below.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82768/android-question wanted to ask you some things, glad if you help, read in chats. will delete the comment later.