# Rotate bitmap multiple times makes image blur how to avoid it

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I wanted to rotate the images as much as the user clicks on rotate button.The code below makes the image rotated correctly but my image is becoming blur.

I've been using the code below:

```
 backLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i=0;i<selectedImageList.size();i++) {

                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageList.get(i), bmOptions);
                Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
                matrix.preRotate(0);
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.
                        createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);

                File file=Utility.createFileFromBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                File oldFile=new File(selectedImageList.get(i));
                LogUtil.error("Deleted Name",oldFile.getAbsolutePath()+"-->"+file.getAbsolutePath());
                oldFile.delete();
                itemList.set(selectedImages.get(i),file.getAbsolutePath());
                selectedImageList.set(i,file.getAbsolutePath());
                mSnapRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
```

[image: Below ll be the image]

Comment: Don't rotate the bitmap. Rotate the `ImageView`.

Comment: check this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259534/how-to-rotate-image-in-imageview-on-button-click-each-time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016126/when-click-a-button-rotate-image-clockwise-in-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915142/android-rotate-image-inside-the-button ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623291/rotating-image-in-android-with-a-button

Comment: @lavanya lavan : have u found solution for this . Me too facing same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

/

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{                  
    imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + 90);
}
```