# Rotate an imageView at an angle using Seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I simply want to rotate `an image from min to max`. But for that i have used **multiple images to show Progress**. Can some one suggest me a way to use a single image. which can rotate at an angle from min to max.

I know there are two possible ways to achieve it.

1. Using Animation Classes
2. Custom View

[image]

**I simply want to rotate this image using SeekBar in any number of steps**.

How can i achieve this?

**To roate an Image**

```
private void rotate(float degree) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    imgview.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}
```

**Second Approach**

```
imageView.setRotation(angle); // but requires API >= 11
```

**I can use Matrix**

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

How can i **set Start and end angle to SeekBar min and max** respectively. Which approach is better and Whether i must put it in `FrameLayout` to let it `rotate freely`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way :

```
// load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
       R.drawable.android);

int width = bitmapOrg.width();
int height = bitmapOrg.height();

// createa matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// rotate the Bitmap
matrix.postRotate(45);

// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

// make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
// to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

// set the Drawable on the ImageView
imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

For details check this out.

http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

```
matrix.postRotate(45);  //here 45 is the degree of angle to rotate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Matrix as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an infinite rotation but you could spin it however you want.
This view just spins 360 degrees infinitely.

```
        final RotateAnimation R = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, view.getWidth() / 2.0f, view.getHeight() / 2.0f);
            R.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            R.setDuration(800);
            view.startAnimation(R);
```