# How to rotate Bitmap 45 degrees

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

How to `rotate` `Bitmap` 45 degrees?

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(degrees);
mBitmapFirst = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapFirst, 0, 0, mBitmapFirst.getWidth(), mBitmapFirst.getHeight());
mImageFirstView.setImageBitmap(mBitmapFirst);
```

I used this method, but it working only if `rotation` 90 `degrees`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can rotate to 45 degree with this example :

```
Matrix minMatrix = new Matrix();
//height and width are set earlier.
Bitmap minBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas minCanvas = new Canvas(minBitmap);

int minwidth = bitmapMin.getWidth();  
int minheight = bitmapMin.getHeight();
int centrex = minwidth/2;
int centrey = minheight/2;

minMatrix.setRotate(mindegrees, centrex, centrey);
Bitmap newmin = Bitmap.createBitmap(minBitmap, 0, 0, (int) minwidth, (int) minheight, minMatrix, true);

minCanvas.drawBitmap(newmin, (centrex - newmin.getWidth()/2), (centrey - newmin.getHeight()/2), null);
minCanvas.setBitmap(minBitmap);
```

where mindegree is your rotation degree,

hope i helps you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10104318/3210285)
 where use has also achieved memory saving by saving the need for creating new bitmap every time