# How to rotate a imageView in portrait / landscape changing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have a layout with a `ImageView` that I want to keep similar in  landscape and portrait orientations, such as this figure:

[image: Portrait and landscape layouts]

I'm using two similar layouts (layout and layout-land). In the second layout, I add the `android:rotation` parameter such in code below, but it resulted in this figure:

[image: Landscape]

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/background_agogo" />
```

Is it possible to rotate the image view using only xml layout file? How could I do it?

Comment: The image itself will have orientation info embedded, so you don't need the android:rotation.   Images should come in rotated properly.  The layout should control the aspect ratio relative to the screen

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your activities xml in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Then in your Fragment/Activity, whatever contains the ImageView, override `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` and in there you can check `if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` and then you could rotate your ImageView programmatically `image.setRotation(90)` Note that setRotation requires API 11 or higher. Otherwise refer to this answer for how to rotate programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10104318/4898635

For more information on handling runtime changes like orientation, check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
android:src = "@drawable/background_agogo"
```

use

```
android:background="@drawable/background_agogo"
```

The image should stretch to fit the imageview when using the background attribute.