# Android - How to rotate imageview on touch

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, touch

I have an imageview layer and I want to rotate it on touch and stop It when I touch again, how can I do?

Comment: same question was answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Animation **rotate.xml** in **anim** dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Now in you class file load animation

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.rotate);
```

And on click of your image start animation

```
your_image.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: thanks and last question How Can I handle if I touch again the image I need to stop animation ?

Comment: Take one boolean isAnimationRunning and set it to true when animation started and vice versa. When you click image only start animation if not running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set an animation programmatically like this:

```
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
    0.5f);

   rotate.setDuration(4000);
   rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
   yourView.setAnimation(rotate);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to do ontouch rotate and ontouch again stop rotation?