# Is there any API in Android for rotation of images?

Tags: android

I have sequence of images, based on the touch or swipe of screen i need to change these images to provide a 360 rotation feel.. eg if there is single touch based on the touch gesture i will change a single image.. For swipe i am using matrix and touch gesture to calculate the swipe distance and based on the distance calculated, change the images... Is there any API that can preform all these..

Comment: Did you even put an effort to search before posting the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10104318/2826147

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an imageView use **Matrix** for rotation

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate( angleValue, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks AkSiddique and Ait Vaghela.. I waned to slightly modify the question.. I have sequence of images based on the touch of the screen i need to change these images. eg if there is single touch on left side based on the touch gesture i will change the image. I wanted to know if there is any api  for this else i need to write a separate logic for single touch, double touch and change of images  based on the gesture.

Comment: @S.SunilKumar, you have to write your own logic for this. **P.S** To rotate an ImageView on ontouch at runtime you can set onTouchListener on ImageView & rotate it by adding last two lines(i.e. postRotate matrix & set it on imageView) in above code section in your touch listener ACTION_MOVE part.