# rotate image file with SDK v.23.0

Tags: android

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZbL2ofcdP0&list=PL9jCwTXYWjDJ5Lok6Lba8U_629xeegj_h&index=9) , try to rotate image file to 90 degree after taking a picture , but I can'r call the method `matrix.setRotata` , and when I

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix()   it said Matrix was deprecated
```

so I find other solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle) 
,BUT still , can't find `matrix.postRotate` method

help please