# Click on a button to chance textfield 50% chance

Tags: java, android

im very new to java & android development,
I want a textfield that changes 50% to "You win!" or 50% to "You Lose!" when i click/tap a button.

And a image rotating randomly, like it is 0° then it will get a number between 0 and 100 (higher then 50 is clockwise lower then 50 is counter-clockwise)

i might be asking to much xD but i really dont know how i do this.
How do i do this ?

I actually dont want very advanced answers because im very new to java.
Theres is pretty much nothing in my code except for a button and a textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a little help to start off.
First you should add an OnClickListener to your button:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handleButtonClick();
        }
    });
```

The handleButtonClick()-method could look like this:

```
private void handleButtonClick() {
    // Here we get a random integer between 0 and 99 (including 0 and 99)
    int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(100);
    // Here we check if the random number is even
    boolean isEven = randomNumber % 2 == 0;
    // Now you can do stuff depending on the integer itself (rotation)
    // and depending on whether it's even or not.
    if(randomNumber < 50){
      // do this
    } else {
      // do that
    }

    if(isEven){
      // do this
    } else {
      // do that
    }

}
```

To change the text you use:

```
yourText.setText(...);
```

But this is really basic stuff you could read on [Android TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

And rotating images was discussed here [Android: Rotate image in imageview by an angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

Please read tutorials or refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/) before asking every little thing you could easily look up. Feel free to ask again when you get stuck.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() method gives you a floating point number between 0-1 but not included 1.

All you have to do is:

```
int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random()*101);
if(randomNumber < 50)
    ...
else
    ...
```