# How to rotate, zoom, pinch an imageview in android

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, zooming

I searched but I didn't got any solution for it. I want an image to be zoomin, zoomout, rotate, pinch using fingers.
Can anyone help me and give an example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/devunwired/custom-touch-examples...Go through it

Comment: https://github.com/devunwired/custom-touch-examples

Comment: I think this would help you [Rotate Image in ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

Comment: @vidya sagar in that example only roation is there no zooming option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link would help
[sample code is available](https://github.com/techierishi/ImageGesture)

Comment: I will check now..

Comment: This works for me I can rotate, zoom an imageview. Thankyou.

Comment: so please accept my answer.