# How to create image in different viewing angle android

Tags: android, image, coordinate-transformation

I have an image that I need to rotate to 90 degree inclination and all this have to be done programmatically in android. A top view in mechanical drawing term. 
The image is assumed to be taken at a 0 degree angle.

Is there any way this is possible  ?

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: so instead of 50 high by 100 wide, you want to show it 100 high by 50 wide?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle

Comment: @Palsisch.. thats seems a solution I can attempt .Thanks