# How can I rotate an Image on an axis when clicked in android?

Tags: java, android, button, rotation, imageview

I want something like this. When someone clicks the button it should rotate it in 90 degrees perfectly.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Rotate your bitmap to 90 degree and then assign it again to your imageView.

Try following code:

In your `onCreate` Method,

```
myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myImageView.setImageBitmap(RotateBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)myImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap() , 90));
        }
    });
```

And Create a Method below.

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```