# Rotating ImageView's inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android card game.
I want to display all the players cards, and so I created 4 LinearLayouts.
1 for top player, left side player, right side player, and the bottom player.

I am trying to use the same images for the cards, and therefor I try to rotate the cards of the side players (left and right players).

For some reason, the top and bottom players cards looks good, but the side players cards are too small.

This is my left player layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.026"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.381">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_left_card_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:rotation="90" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_left_card_5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:rotation="90" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_left_card_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:rotation="90" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_left_card_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:rotation="90" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player_left_card_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:rotation="90" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Although the height should be 200 and width 80, the cards are smaller.
I suspect the card sizes are being calculated before the rotation, and then the rotation shrinks them somehow, it seems like the cards width of the left player is the same width as the top player, but it should be bigger because of the rotation.

How can I rotate the cards, but keep them at their original size?
Thanks.

Here is a screenshot from the game.

[image: Screenshot from the game]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect the card sizes are being calculated before the rotation, and then the rotation shrinks them somehow..

I think this might be wrong. Android calculates final width and height measurements and accommodate in the Layout. Because it is concerned with what it displays finally and it refers the properties that you have mentioned.

Try giving `wrap_content` in width or height or both for indivdual cards in the `ImageView` like -

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also note `200dp` should accomodate all 5 cards width plus the padding that you have (`2dp` per card). And `80dp` width should accomodate the height of your card plus `2dp` padding. Else give higher `layout_width` and `layout_height` for `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I tried what you said, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: try `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `LinearLayout` may be?