# rotate images in random duration

Tags: android, random, image-rotation

i want to make a truth or dare app.i want to rotate an image in random duration.

according to code below(i found it in [Android: Rotate image in imageview by an angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/android-rotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle))
i made an animation xml and set a duration for it.

```
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="45"
  android:toDegrees="45"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="0"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

i guess i shall use a random function in main activity to get random number for random duration.

so, how shall i put this random number (which i got in main activity) in duration in animation xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [setDuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setDuration%28long%29) method of Animation to set duration programaticaally

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.your_animation);
animation.setDuration(300);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Most Welcome @dark.zara