# Android ImageView to Bitmap after rotating

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap, android-gesture

I want to create a bitmap from an imageView, but I first need to rotate my imageView before converting the bitmap. I use the following code to convert the imageView to Bitmap.

```
 BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgPhoto.getDrawable();
 Bitmap photo = drawable.getBitmap();
```

The imageView implements a rotation gesture. I want to be able to rotate the imageView and then create a Bitmap using the rotated imageView. However, it seems my Bitmap is still getting the original imageView instead of the rotated position. The following is the complete code. Thank you.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RotationGestureDetector.OnRotationGestureListener{

private ImageView imgPhoto, imgBackground, imgCombine;
private RotationGestureDetector mRotationDetector;
private Button btnCombine;
private float angle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRotationDetector = new RotationGestureDetector(this);

    imgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
    imgBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBackground);
    collageImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCombine);

    btnCombine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCombineImage);
    btnCombine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgPhoto.getDrawable();
            Bitmap photo = drawable.getBitmap();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector) {
    angle = rotationDetector.getAngle();
    Log.d("RotationGestureDetector", "Rotation: " + Float.toString(angle));
    imgPhoto.setRotation(imgPhoto.getRotation() + (-angle));
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To rotate ImageView:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10104318/7639113

Then you can create the bitmap by using DrawingCache,

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code after the onClick. It should provide a rotated bitmap with the angle specified.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(angle);
Bitmap rotatedPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: I'm getting a method cannot be resolve error.                                    
                Bitmap rotatedPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgPhoto, 0, 0, imgPhoto.getWidth(), imgPhoto.getHeight(), matrix, true);

Answer (score 0):

The rotate effect is actually applied at the Canvas level. So, what you can do is get the current Canvas augmentations and then draw your Bitmap into a new one with the changes.

```
           Matrix transformMatrix =  imgPhoto.getImageMatrix()

            Bitmap original = photo;

            Bitmap adjusted = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(),
                    original.getHeight(),
                    original.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(adjusted);
            canvas.setMatrix(transformMatrix);
            canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);

            //at this point adjusted bitmap contains the rotated image
```