# I am using Android animations to rotate an ImageView, but the movement is very choppy

Tags: android, animation, graphics

So this is my XML animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0" 
    android:toDegrees="360" 
    android:pivotX="50%" 
    android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

I am applying this to an ImageView as a means to rotate an image. But the movement is very choppy. Every time the image rotates, it appears to skip at two points in its rotation that are 180 degrees away from each other. I can't see any reason why this is happening, has anyone run into this difficulty and found a fix?

Comment: Try going from 0 to 359 degrees.

Comment: Are you trying in the emulator or on a real device? Should be smooth on a mid-to-high-end device.

Comment: Not the slightest problem here when I try to use your animation in one of my projects. Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.2.

Comment: Have you tried enabling hardware acceleration?  This made my animation incredibly smoother. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a smooth image rotation in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a different interpolator. FYI, the default interpolator used when creating animations in android is not a linear interpolator, but instead `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`.

Comment: I need a smooth linear rotation. I'm animating a turning wheel

Comment: are you perhaps applying the rotate effect together with some other effect? (i.e move effect or something? cause that might definitely be an issue).

Comment: Nope, the ImageView is static, set by a standard XML layout. The image source is done in the same, standard way. This is the only effect I am applying to it

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you did not get right result. This works for me

You can use the built-in android.R.anim.linear_interpolator from your animation XML file with

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator".
```

Or you can create your own XML interpolation file in your project, e.g. name it

res/anim/linear_interpolator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And add to your animation XML:

```
android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator"
```

and use

```
android:toDegrees="360"
```

to

```
android:toDegrees="359"
```

as 360 and 0 degree are same

Answer (score 0):

An emulator is always choppy. Try debugging it in a device. Speed up the rotation if not.

Answer (score 0):

If this rotation is so much important, I guess it's very important part of your UI.

In that kind of situation you should get interested in simple OpenGL implementation which will help you with your problem.

I suggest using http://www.andengine.org/ - simple and easy to implement.

On [AndEngineExamples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/Rotation3DExample.java) you can find fine sample of code which is even too much!

Answer (score -1):

try this make an xml file in drawable and put your drawable there code is below, name this file my_progress_indeterminate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/your_rotating_image"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Sorry, but you have to put it in progress bar like this is simple if the image is static same as image view dont need to do any different coding for this simply write like this in your layout xml file:

```
 <ProgressBar android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp"></ProgressBar>
```

Comment: what if you need an imageview, or just an animation id to run on your views?