# Is the structure of this code suitable for its purpose and how do I smooth animations in Android?

Tags: android, animation, layout, android-canvas

I am implementing a piano tiles clone for an educational purposes. I've created 5 Views (that's the rows) which extends `LinearLayout`. Each one of them has 4 childs (that's the 4 tiles).

I am using an `Handler` for the animation, and change the `Y` property manually every "tick".
Problem is, the animation is somewhat twitching and not smooth.

I have two questions:

1. Is that a good design? I know for example about `surfaceView` as alternative for drawing and animating but that seemed to me a bit complicated for my cause.
2. How would you animate those tiles? currently I use an `Handler` (actually I was guided on another thread to use `Animation`. What do you think the most feet to my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your grid idea, but you may have to change it if you would like the tiles to be procedurally generated. Also, here is a thread on how to make animations smoother in Java (This can probably apply to Android too):
[How can I make a Java Swing animation smoother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511282/how-can-i-make-a-java-swing-animation-smoother)

Here is one for Android: [Moving animation not smooth in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976932/moving-animation-not-smooth-in-android)

Also, I feel you are a bit behind, the Piano Tiles phase has disappeared now, much like Flappy bird.

Comment: Also, for a more reliable answer, I would recommend splitting your question in to two questions for a wider range of answers. If you do not find an answer that works, SE Programmers could be a suitable place for your question.