# Custom spinner animation not smooth enough: framesCount and frameDuration error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-progressbar

I'm working on a custom indeterminate spinner, I browsed through the SDK for some pointers and found the indeterminate spinner xml file made by Google:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_black_16"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:framesCount="12"
android:frameDuration="100" />
```

When I use this as a drawable in my own project I get errors about `android:framesCount` and `android:framesDuration`. After looking on Google for a while I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19248) link to an issue report.

My questions is: Is there any workaround so i can still use `android:framesCount` and `android:framesDuration`? Or is there any other way I can make my custom spinner rotate smooth?

Comment: Having issues with the same problem: without framesCount and frameDuration the animation isn't smooth enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the answer to this question? [How to make a smooth image rotation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android) It appears that you are having the same issue. He doesn't use the following:

android:framesCount="12"
android:frameDuration="100"

Since it appears to be internal I would recommend going about it the way he did.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the same problem, because the person asking for help is having problems with animation pause on start.

Comment: Just tested it out, setting the iterpolator does not make the rotate animation smoother.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced animated-rotate with rotate

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```