# Flip a view in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Is it possible to flip a view in ViewPager.Basically i want to put several views as in hompage and a view behind every view i.e user must be able to flip the view too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Very Much Possible.

You need Rotation Animation

Look here

[How to make a smooth image rotation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android)

and

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html

I used the above and implemented successfully what you are asking.

Look for its example in api demo of android

Comment: Yes but both the links point to flip part.I specifically want to flip my card that is a viewpager to show other side.How can i implement this?

Comment: I used default gallery to show some cards which shows alphabets. a small i button on press flip the card 180 degree inside and brings the back of the card which has object name starting with the given alphabet

Comment: apidemo project is given in android sdk itself. import that and see for animation examples in it. follow 3d rotation animation example. do the same they did to flip