# Making a custom progressdialog with an animation

Tags: android

I am trying to make my own progressdialog, sort of. I'm just using a Dialog which inflates a Layout. In this layout, I have an `ImageView`, this imageview should rotate just like the original spinner in the `ProgressDialog`. I applied this animation to it:

```
RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    r.setDuration(10000);
    r.setRepeatCount(r.INFINITE);
    icon.startAnimation(r);
```

The animation last for 10000 ms obviously. The animation start slowly and ends slowly, is it possible that the rotation speed is constant at all time?

Comment: Did you try to set a linear interpolator (with `setInterpolator`)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android

Comment: @Henry Make your comment into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `LinearInterpolator` to the animation:

```
r.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Comment: +1. What's odd is that the documentation says that it's linear by default. Seems not!

Answer (score 0):

A way to increase speed rotation is to set a duration and a number in repeatCount field that apply to you. Doing so, you can control the speed... Just put some big big numbers and add a listener to your animation and when it ends, start it again if dialog is still displayed.

Comment: I dont want to increase the speed rotation, I found a perfect rotation speed. But when the animation is finished it slows down, and after like 0.5 seconds it start again. I want to close this gap between the animations.

Comment: well, that this may mean that you're doing lots of things in UI thread when it stops...