# HOw to tilt or Swing a EditText

Tags: android, swing, passwords, android-edittext, tilt

I'm developing an Android Application which contains username and password fields. what i want here is if the user input the wrong password then the password field should tilt or swing (in horizontal direction ) to get the user attention. I've seen like this in imo.im app for android. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could either use view animation(define your animation in an XML file - [How to make a smooth image rotation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android?rq=1)) or do something like this: http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/kinetic-list-view/