# Custom ProgressBar rotates not smoothly

Tags: android, rotation, progress-bar, android-drawable

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android), I created the following files:

`res/drawable/spinner.xml`

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/loading"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="718"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:startOffset="0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 />
```

and `res/layout/layout.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/splashSpinnerImageView"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/spinner"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Still the spinner is rotating with visible hickups and not really smoothly. I tested it with Sony Xperia S and Z2, and it has the same behaviour.

What can I do to increase smothiness of my ProgressBar? Should I convert ProgressBar to ImageView and/or start the animation programmatically?

TIA

UPDATE:

I tried using the default android's `progress_large.xml` in my project, but the most 'interesting' attributes

```
android:framesCount="12"
android:frameDuration="100"
```

couldn't be found as they are defined private

Comment: post @drawable/splash_spinner

Comment: fixed the typo, it is not splash_spinner but spinner

Comment: what you defined in res/drawable/spinner.xml is not a Drawable,  it's an Animation

Comment: try to remove every attribute from rotate tag and leave android:drawable="@drawable/loading" only

Comment: removing the attributes didn't help much.

Comment: ok,  does the default ProgressBar runs well? if so see drawable/progress_medium.xml file

Comment: hmm, tried to remove them?

Comment: of course, coming back to the original problem

Comment: well, too bad, i cannot help more if that doesnt work...

Comment: I found a problem. I'll answer my own question, but I would like to thank you for your time by voting your answer up. Put you comment about the default PB as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem somewhere else. For my top-most RelativeLayout I used a PNG 1080x1920 as a background. It weighed 480 kB and with this one even the default `ProgressBar' - thanks to #pskink 's hint - was spinning with hickups.

Then I tried to make it smaller with 720x1280 pixels resolution @ 360 kB, and - magic! - the spinner started to rotate smoothly!

Android seems to have problems with hi-res pics...