# Android development: To create image that rotating

Tags: android

I'm aiming to create a live wallpaper of an image that simply rotates endlessly. Could anyone give me a hint of the code to rotate an image view? I'm using Android Studio by the way.

Thank you

Comment: even you use Rotation Animation and the repeat count is infinity, or you draw it on canvas and rotate the canvas

Comment: could you show how to do it? im kinda new in this android development stuff and i never touched java either... i thought asking question as simple as rotating an image is fine

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android