# An Android Interpolator using 4 numbers

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want program an Android Interpolator, UI designer gave me 4 numbers about Interpolator. And I don't know how to use these numbers. Is it need to write a custom defined Interpolator? How to program it? Thanks.

> Name: rotate
>
> Start: 0(ms)
>
> Dur:100(ms)
>
> Val: 0 degree >>> -15 degree
>
> **Interpolator:(0.2, 0, 0.8, 1)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a smooth image rotation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

> UI designer gave me 4 numbers about Interpolator

The four values are the control points of a bezier curve.

> Is it need to write a custom defined Interpolator?

You don't need to create your custom `Interpolator` from scratch, use `PathInterpolatorCompat.create()` instead.

```java
PathInterpolatorCompat.create(0.2, 0, 0.8, 1)
```