# Rotate a button in Android

Tags: android

I'd like to gradually rotate one of my buttons in my Android application with the following code:

```
  for(int i=0; i<90; i++)
  {
        myButton.setRotation(i);
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

The sleep is only there to have a bit of a delay between the phases.

Once I run the code the button rotates by 90 degrees, but without gradually rotating, it simply jumps to 90 rotation.

How should I modify my code to show the in-between states as well?

Comment: It is better to use animation to rotate your button, maybe this link will be helpful : https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-rotate-animation-example.html and this link : https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-rotate-animations-clockwise-anti-clockwise-with-examples

Comment: use like this `myButton.animate().rotation(90).setDuration(1000).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());`

Comment: did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634252/how-to-make-a-smooth-image-rotation-in-android

Comment: Do not use `sleep` method in your main thread, because it freezes the UI. If you want to introduce a delay, use `Handler.postDelayed` method.

Answer (score 1):

create xml file in your anim folder name `rotate_ninety`

```
<rotate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="90" />
```

then replace your loop with this code

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_ninety);
    myButton.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to rotate your button:

```
long rotation = 90; //insert number of degrees here

myButton.animate()
     .rotation(rotation)
     .setDuration(500) //500 is half a second
     .setStartDelay(100) //this is optional
     .start();
```

For extra information on the ViewPropretyAnimator, look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator).