# Android animate drawable

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, animationdrawable

I'd like to display an animated drawable in my app.

Just to make the reader visualize what I have in mind, I need an air-conditioning unit that emits flows of air; the "power" of the flows should be adjustable.

It would be something like the animation of the Earth one can find in [this](https://github.com/FredJul/Warmd) app.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9yON.gif)  to the animation.

I've found the `AnimationDrawable`class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable) but this is a frame-by-frame animation, so I'd have to create lots of images.

I was woldering what would be the best way to create such an animation.

I apologize for the lack of specificity of this question but I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a `RotateAnimation` because it was the easiest option to achieve what I wanted.

To make the rotation smooth  I followed what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343281/9578198) StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use your drawable as a background (as i think it is used in the animation with the earth) and for your animation to use canvas.
[Here is an example from a game that uses the same principle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFGtx7Ikfbo).
You can use either the animation with the birds moving, either the one with the bullets. To increase the intensity,increase the speed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lottie animation. It's uses a json format of the animation.

check this library :
[airbnb/lottie-android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)